# How to dynamic show(hide) action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My application contains a single AppCompatActivity and some Fragments, in some fragments, I want to hide the action bar (for example, the login fragment), in other fragments, I want to show the action bar. The application has a theme `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">`, this theme has an action bar, I want to know how to show or hide the action bar dynamically in code.

I have tried `getSupportActionBar().hide();` but this only made the action bar
translucence,it's still hold the space.

Comment: It seams that when you use action bar through the application theme,then you can not hide it using getSupportActionBar().hide().if you add Toolbar in the xml manually,and add it in your MainActivity,Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);setSupportActionBar(toolbar); then you can hide it using getSupportActionBar().hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a Theme with no ActionBar and adding your own Toolbar into your `activity_layout.xml`. Once you have it in your layout you can easily hide it with `toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. If you'd like to animate hiding and showing it, you can do so with `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`. Depending on the effect you'd like to achieve, you can also try setting a `translationY` to hide the toolbar from the screen.